# Search for a word in webView that opens pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

I'm using the following code to open pdf file in webView

```
WebView webview=new WebView(SpecialityAllManuals.this);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

I want to do search for a word in it, is this possible?

Comment: do you want to find the word and want to highlight the search word in in webview?

Comment: where r u storing the page content?In database.?

Comment: No I open the pages from the pdf file link directly, I'm not sorting anything in database.

Comment: your application has different scenario then that of my applicaiton i have implemented in my application in other way. Actually i have saved page content into db and then i m retrieving the page content and replace the search keyword to the page..but in your case i don't know how to do that.

Comment: but is it possible to save page content programmatically and dynamically?

Comment: ya it depends how you want to display pages on webview.

Comment: I want display the pages as the original pdf file in server.

Comment: I'm using the webView as I wrote in my question

Comment: k dude got it i think ur application scenario is very different then that of mine so can't help.because as i have told you i m saving page contents to db and then replaced the search keyword in my page..may some other developer help to u.

Comment: ok could you explain how to use this way with viewpager ?

Comment: i m going to post it in your answer copy paste it then i will remove my answer.because comments r not good to use.

Comment: ok post as answer, no problem :)

Comment: u can download PDFs then separate it into pages and can use as i have explained.There should be better work around here.I hope u will get your answer.

Comment: @Eman87 Did you solved your problem!?